# Can I use private indicator's signals in Strategy Tester on Tradinview?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have a private indicator that gives me buy/sell signals. Is it possible to use the indicator's buy/sell signals as points of trade entry with Pinescript to create a Strategy Tester?

I was looking at this, but not quite sure if this is the right way to import my indicator.

```
signalFromStudy = input(close, "Input", input.source)
```

Also, unsure of how to access the buy/sell value. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible. however, there is the possibility of converting the indicator into a strategy, and from there it will be possible to access the information of the panel tester as well as having the possibility of accessing the section relating to capital.

Comment: Is that also possible with private indicators where I cannot see the source code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, if you dont see the source code you cant edit.